# Generate all results in one button click - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Just to start let me just say in not good at Javascript.

I am developing a simple ROI calculator where when someone enter the number of devices for his network support company it will show the user his current cost and the cost that we provide the service for. The problem is that when i press generate cost all the information do not get generated all at once. I have to click the "Generate cost" button twice more to get all the result.

I have to click the "Generate cost" button twice more to get the result for our cost and our saving.

I just want to know how i can make sure that when i click the button all the text boxes gets populated rather than me clicking twice more to generate the rest of the results.

I have generated the file here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwpePX

HTML

```
<h1 style="font-size:40px;text-align:center;">ROI Calculator</h1>

<br/>
<div style="float:left;">
     <h1>Your Cost</h1>
Total no. of managed servers
    <input type="roi_text" id="value1" name="value1" value="" />
    <br/>Total no. of network devices
    <input type="roi_text" id="value2" name="value2" value="" />
    <br/>Total no. of workstations
    <input type="roi_text" id="value3" name="value3" value="" />
    <br/>No of service desk users
    <input type="roi_text" id="value4" name="value4" value="" />
    <br/>How many engineers do you have?
    <input type="roi_text" id="value5" name="value5" value="" />
    <br/>Average salary of your engineers*
    <input type="roi_text" id="value6" name="value6" value="" />
    <br/>Average on-call allowance per month?
    <input type="roi_text" id="value7" name="value7" value="" />
    <br/>
    <br/>Your Current Cost
    <input type="roi_text" id="answer" name="answer" value="" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
     <h1>Our Cost</h1>
NOC =
    <input type="roi_text" id="answer1" name="answer1" value="" disabled="disabled" />
    <br/>Out of Hour NOC =
    <input type="roi_text" id="answer2" name="answer2" value="" disabled="disabled" />
    <br/>24/7 Service desk =
    <input type="roi_text" id="answer3" name="answer3" value="" disabled="disabled" />
    <br/>Out of Hours SD =
    <input type="roi_text" id="answer4" name="answer4" value="" disabled="disabled" />
    <br/>Our cost =
    <input type="roi_text" id="answer5" name="answer5" value="" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>Total Savings =
    <input type="roi_text" id="answer7" name="answer7" value="" />
    <input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="GENERATE COST" onclick="javascript:addNumbers();" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
     function addNumbers() {
 var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
 var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
 var val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value3").value);
 var val4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value4").value);
 var val5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value5").value);
 var val6 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value6").value);
 var val7 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value7").value);
 var noc1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer1").value);
 var oohnoc1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer2").value);
 var sd1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer3").value);
 var oohsd1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer4").value);
 var ansD1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer").value);
 var inbaycost1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer5").value);


 var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
 ansD.value = (val5 * val6 + val7 * 12);

 var noc = document.getElementById("answer1");
 noc.value = ((val1 * 25 + val2 * 10 + val3 * 5) * 12);

 var oohnoc = document.getElementById("answer2");
 oohnoc.value = ((val1 * 15 + val2 * 5 + val3 * 3.5) * 12);

 var sd = document.getElementById("answer3");
 sd.value = ((val4 * 15) * 12);

 var oohsd = document.getElementById("answer4");
 oohsd.value = ((val4 * 10) * 12);

 var inbaycost = document.getElementById("answer5");
 inbaycost.value = (noc1 + oohnoc1 + sd1 + oohsd1);

 var totalsaving = document.getElementById("answer7");
 totalsaving.value = (ansD1 - inbaycost1); }
```

Will appericiate any help to sort this issue.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making in wrong order. 
Example: you take te value of "answer4"

```
var oohsd1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer4").value);
```

then calculate its value

```
var oohsd = document.getElementById("answer4");
oohsd.value = ((val4 * 10) * 12);
```

This is how it works

```
function addNumbers() {
 var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
 var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
 var val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value3").value);
 var val4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value4").value);
 var val5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value5").value);
 var val6 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value6").value);
 var val7 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value7").value);

 var noc = document.getElementById("answer1");
 noc.value = ((val1 * 25 + val2 * 10 + val3 * 5) * 12);
 var noc1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer1").value);

 var oohnoc = document.getElementById("answer2");
 oohnoc.value = ((val1 * 15 + val2 * 5 + val3 * 3.5) * 12);
 var oohnoc1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer2").value) ;

 var sd = document.getElementById("answer3");
 sd.value = ((val4 * 15) * 12);

 var oohsd = document.getElementById("answer4");
 oohsd.value = ((val4 * 10) * 12);

 var oohsd1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer4").value);

 var sd1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer3").value);

 var inbaycost = document.getElementById("answer5");
 inbaycost.value = (noc1 + oohnoc1 + sd1 + oohsd1);


 var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
 ansD.value = (val5 * val6 + val7 * 12);
 var ansD1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer").value);

 var inbaycost1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer5").value);

 var totalsaving = document.getElementById("answer7");
 totalsaving.value = (ansD1 - inbaycost1);
}
```

Link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbqjXpv